# Create a custom address book for Outlook 2010 programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'd like to create a **Custom Contact List** (*or address book as it's called*) so that in Outlook the user will be looking at "Suggested Contact", "Contacts" etc., and then, "Custom Contacts". I went off and tried the following.

```
int count = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists.Count;
```

This gives me the value of 8. So, naturally, I've tried to `Add` something to the address list object but guess what - there's no such method. It's nothing strange about that, since the API clearly states that it's read-only object. However, I need to set up an address book/list (*whatever it's called*) for my client.

How do I add a new **Address Book** to Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an **Outlook Address Book** entry by using the following code:

```cs
Outlook.Folder contacts = this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.Folder addressBook = contacts.Folders.Add("Business Contacts", Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
addressBook.ShowAsOutlookAB = true; // force display in Outlook Address Book
Outlook.ContactItem contact = addressBook.Items.Add();
contact.FullName = "Custom Industries, Inc.";
contact.Email1Address = "sales@customindustries.com";
contact.Save();
```

Comment: I I'm not too retarded by now, I see that you use a folder-thingy (default folder for contacts on line 1). Then you create an other, entirely new (sub) folder. Then, you show it in into the default one. Is that correctly perceived? That wasn't as straight-forward as I was hoping for... Could you also point me to some documentation on this method?

Comment: You can create a new Contact folder using [`Folders.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862204.aspx) Then you can add a new Contact using [`Items.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861028.aspx). The trick to seeing this in the address book is toggling [`Folder.ShowAsOutlookAB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868790.aspx).

Comment: Nice... Who came up with the name?! I missed that AB-thingy... In Sweden it stands for "Inc." or "Limited" if you will. Should be IsAddressBook and settable.

Comment: Glad it helped you out! Strange naming, no doubt. I had to locate the AB toggle via the UI first (*Folder Properties -> Outlook Address Book*) then found the class property.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate the last part, please. What do you mean by locating a toggle via the UI? It sounds like if you have source code to Outlook...

Comment: I just used the Outlook UI Properties window to determine how things were added to the local Address Book. I don't have the source. ;-)