# Determine if an address book exists in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I've created an address book as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302683/create-a-custom-address-book-for-outlook-2010-programmatically) and that works like a charm. Then I'd like to access it - first checking if it exists (and creating it in the opposite case), then referencing it.

My current code is relying on an `Exception` to detect missing name folder, which, in my view, is an ugly work-around. I haven't found a neater method, like e.g. `.DoesFolderExist` or such. I'd like to get an suggestion on how to improve it.

```
Outlook.Folder contacts = 
  this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
    Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.Folder addressBook = null;

try { addressBook = contacts.Folders["My AB"] as Outlook.Folder; }
catch (Exception) { }

if (addressBook == null)
{
    addressBook = contacts.Folders.Add("My AB", 
      Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
    addressBook.ShowAsOutlookAB = true;
}
```

Should I be using `this.Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(...)` instead? The problem there is that I need to specify both the name of the address book (which I have) and a store id (which I don't have). I prefer not to go there but the syntax of the method `GetFolderFromID` suggests that there could be two different address books with equal names but placed in different stores. Is it so or does `contact.Folder["name"]` above suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the try/catch-statement approach, but a better one is to iterate through each `Folder` to avoid the exception and performance hit.

```cs
Outlook.Folders contactFolders = contacts.Folders;
if (contactFolders.Cast<Outlook.Folder>()
  .Where(c => c.Name == "My AB").Count() > 0)
    addressBook = contactFolders["My AB"] as Outlook.Folder;
```