# Removing removed items in Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

According to the docs, when I remove a contact from an address book, it is moved to a "removed"-folder. Suppose there's a lazy programmer (not you nor me, of course) who doesn't want to write the code to **update** the contacts on each start of Outlook but simply removes **all** the contacts from an address book and then repopulates it (let's say there are not that many users to populate with and that Outlook is started a large number of times each day), so that the performance isn't an issue but the increasingly huge amount of entries in the deleted folder is.

Does Outlook manage the storage of deletes neatly or do I need, hrmp..., does *that* lazy programmer need to worry about it?

The said programmer would probably be using code that looks something like exactly this.

```
Outlook.Folder contacts = 
  this.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
    Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts) as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.Folder addressBook = contacts.Folders["lazy"] as Outlook.Folder;

while (addressBook.Items.Count > 0)
  addressBook.Items.OfType<Outlook.ContactItem>().Last().Delete();
```

If he needs to worry, He'd probably want to delete the deletes from the deletion folder but, of course, **only** those that were deleted by his software. Is there a smooth way to delete-delete a contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just re-create the `Folder` every time and avoid the slow one-by-one `ContactItem` deletions. When you remove the `Folder` it will not keep a copy in the deleted items. One `Folder` delete & save will be faster than a large number of item deletions.

```cs
Outlook.Folders contactFolders = contacts.Folders;
if (contactFolders.Cast<Outlook.Folder>()
  .Where(c => c.Name == "My AB").Count() > 0)
    contactFolders["My AB"].Delete();
```

Just follow the [address book creation steps from the previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12305103/175679).

Comment: Ah, I got so hung up on the individual contacts that I forgot about the bigger picture. Never the less, I want to be able in doing both this **and** that so I'm glad I got that sorted out. And, of course, thanks for the hint. Acceptance will (probably) follow shortly.

Comment: I tried to be a nice boy and delete the permanently delete the folder but I got into access rights issues. Any hints on that or should I ask a totally new question (if it's a more complicated issue)?

Comment: I'd pose a new question since the above works out fine for me. You just need to include the error message in your new post.

Comment: OK. Just to be clear - the above work perfectly on my machine too. I get into problems when I start playing around with the deleted items folder. Your solution is flawless. I'm just worried about a huge storage overload if I delete too much stuff into the delete items folder.

Comment: You shouldn't have to touch the deleted items folder if you remove the entire `Folder`. When you issue [`Folder.Delete()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863914.aspx), the item is permanently removed - it is not copied to the deleted items folder unless you issue a [`Folder.Move(folderDeletedItems)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865640).